# Get iOS Pressure Updates in Background

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, pressure

I am looking for a way to get barometric pressure data (not altitude) every 10 or so minutes while the app is in the background or while another app is running in the foreground. Is this possible? If so, how?

If not, then how do apps like [Pressur](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pressur/id928096515?mt=8) work?

Comment: Altitude and pressure are sort of the same...

Comment: @matt The barometric pressure can change from day to day at sea level.  I am looking for these types of detailed measurements.

Comment: Yes, and the CMAltimeter gives them to you. I don't understand how you can have a question about that. Did you _look_ at CMAltimeter? That's what an altimeter _is_, it measures _pressure_.

Answer (score 0):

Core Motion gives you CMAltimeter. CMAltimeter gives you CMAltitudeData. CMAltitudeData gives you [`pressure`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltitudedata/1616152-pressure).

(Running in the background is another matter; you cannot run in the background merely in order to use Core Motion, so you'll have to find some other reason to run in the background.)

Comment: What do you mean by "some other reason to run in the background"?  Do mean that I have to perform some other background process, and use the CMAltimeter along with it?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Can you give me a lead on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I suggest [searching Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Core+motion+background+iOS+). The matter has been discussed and explained there many times.

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive *background* `CoreMotion` updates you need to do several things, but it boils down to running `CoreLocation` in the background.  CoreMotion will not run in the background on its own.

- Request authorization via `Info.plist` Privacy strings (*"Location Always and When In Use"* and *"Location When In Use"*)
- Add the Background Modes Capability to your project via the second tab on your app's Project pane.  Enable Location Updates.
- Create the managers and instances you require:

  ```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager() // Not required in this case
    let altimeter = CMAltimeter()
  ```
- Set your location manager's `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to true
- Register the appropriate callbacks, in this case you want a `CMAltimeter` instance and something like:

```
if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
    altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in
    /* Handle Altitude changes here */
    }
}
```

Unlike the other sensors (e.g. `motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval`) you don't appear to have control over how often this is called; it's up to you to average or discard values as appropriate.

I've got an (increasingly less and less) simple demo of background sensor data collection [in a repo here](https://github.com/robinmacharg/iOS-Background-Motion-updates).